# Escape character being included in string

Tags: c++, strcat

Having a weird problem

```
sprintf(tmp, "\"%s\"", filename);
```

I expect the output to be

```
"filename"
```

but instead I get

```
\"filename\"
```

What is going on here?

=============================

```
extern "C" void __export __pascal MyFunc(LPTSTR m_avi, LPTSTR m_mpg)
{
  int frameRate = 20;
  char szAVI[MAX_PATH], szMPG[MAX_PATH];

#ifdef UNICODE
  wcstombs(szAVI, m_avi, _tcslen(m_avi) + 1);
  wcstombs(szMPG, m_mpg, _tcslen(m_mpg) + 1);
#else
  strcpy(szAVI, m_avi);
  strcpy(szMPG, m_mpg);
#endif

  //Call to ffmpeg.exe
  char cmdline[1000] = "ffmpeg ", tmp[50];

  //Overwrite without asking
  strcat(cmdline, "-y ");

  //Input file
  sprintf(tmp, "-i \"%s\" ", szAVI);
  strcat(cmdline, tmp);

  //Lock output at 20 frames per second
  sprintf(tmp, "-r %i ", frameRate);
  strcat(cmdline, tmp);

  //Output file
  sprintf(tmp, "\"%s\"", szMPG);
  strcat(cmdline, tmp);

  WinExec(cmdline, SW_HIDE);
}
```

Comment: Can we see the rest of the program, like something on http://ideone.com ?

Comment: Yeah, there's not enough info here to tell. This works fine for me: http://ideone.com/EEhxH

Comment: That's pretty strange.  Must be something going on with compiler options or a previous #include or #pragma.  As the others said, need to see more code.

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you are doing but I do not get what you get.  My output is "filename".  Can you post a larger code sample?

Comment: Did you copy-paste the backslash (or anything else)? It could be a different representation than the one the compiler uses.

Comment: I have posted the entire function, hopefully that will help

Comment: Just because the code is extern "C" doesn't mean you have to use disgusting C hackery to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the code you've shown doesn't actually produce any output, I suspect the "output" you're talking about is coming from your debugger, where you're attempting to inspect the value of your array before you call `WinExec`.

Debuggers often display the values of variables using the syntax of the language being debugged. The debugger in this case is showing you that the string variable contains quotation marks. Since quotation marks are special in C++, the debugger also displays backslashes to indicate that the quotation marks are part of the string's contents, not denoting the start or end of a string value.

If you're seeing backslashes in the debugger, then everything's fine. If you're seeing backslashes printed out or displayed somewhere in your program, then you need to go look at *that* code since the code here in the question doesn't display anything.